# Stochastic Integral Evaluation

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

We want to evaluate:

$$
\int_{z=0}^T \int_{s=0}^z dW(s) dW(z)
$$

But I don't really understand how to approach the problem. Is this just zero? Why?

Comment: you are computing $\int_0^T W_t\,dW_t$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed as mentioned in comments we have

$$\int_{z=0}^T \int_{s=0}^z dW(s) dW(z)=\int_{0}^{T}W_{s}dW_{s}$$

and so using Itô-formula we get

$$=\frac{1}{2}(W_{T}^{2}-T).$$

Generally, multiple Itô integrals are given in terms of Hermite polynomials (see [notes](https://researchers.ms.unimelb.edu.au/%7Exgge@unimelb/Files/Notes/The%20Wiener-Ito%20Decomposition%20and%20Multiple%20Wiener%20Integrals.pdf) on The Wiener-Itô Chaos Decomposition and Multiple Wiener integrals)

$$n!H_{n}(W(h))=\int_{T^{n}}h(t_{1})\cdots h(t_{n})dW_{t_{1}}\cdots dW_{t_{n}}.$$